# I am trying to find the function f that satisfies $\cos x=f '(x)+f(-x)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

$\cos x=f '(x)+f(-x)$

I manage to solve $f '(x)+f(x)= \cos x$, starting first by solving $y'=-y$ using $y=\exp(ax)$. But here I get stuck because of $f(-x)$.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Please give us more context so we can help you. Do you understand first-order linear ordinary differential equations? If not, what mathematics do you understand that could solve the problem (what have you learned so far)? Do you understand why this equation does not quite fit that categorization? Do you know how to use power series to solve ODEs? And so on.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand first order differential equation but I can not apply the method I know to solve the problem. I have twice derived the equation and was unable to transfom it into a form I recognize. I know a little bit about power series.

Comment: Define $g(x)=f(x)+f(-x)$ and $h(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$. Then derive an ODE system for these functions, solve it and check if it is possible to reconstruct $f(x)=\frac12(g(x)+h(x))$ with sensible behavior around $x=0$.

Comment: Rory, I do not understand why the equation does not fit in the categorizations I indicated first.

Comment: Thanks Lutzl ksnx

Comment: Thanks Lutzl but  I do not manage to follow your advice. As I have tried to precise : I manage to solve f '(x)+f(x)= cosx, starting first by solving y'=-y using y=exp(ax). But here I get stuck because of f(-x).

Comment: You would get $$g'(x)=f'(x)-f'(-x)=(\cos(x)-f(-x))-(\cos(-x)-f(x))=h(x),\\ h'(x)=f'(x)+f'(-x)=(\cos(x)-f(-x))+(\cos(-x)-f(x))=2\cos(x)-g(x)$$ which then is essentially the same as the answer of Christian Blatter.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $f$ is a solution valid on all of ${\mathbb R}$. Then we can write $f$ in the form $f(x)=u(x)+v(x)$ with $u$ an even and $v$ an odd function of $x$. It follows that we have
$$u'(x)+v'(x)+u(x)-v(x)\equiv \cos x\ .$$
Separating even and odd parts here entails
$$v'(x)+u(x)\equiv\cos x,\qquad u'(x)-v(x)\equiv0\ .\tag{1}$$ 
It follows that
$$u''(x)+u(x)\equiv\cos x\ .\tag{2}$$
Now this is an ordinary differential equation, and we want an even solution of this equation. The general solution of the associated homogeneous equation is $u_{\rm hom}(x)=A\cos x+B\sin x$. A particular solution of the given inhomogeneous equation is found by the Ansatz $u_{\rm part}(x):=x(C\cos x+D\sin x)$ and determining the coefficients $C$ and $D$. Plugging the Ansatz into $(2)$ we obtain $C=0$, $D={1\over2}$. It follows that the general even solution of $(2)$ is given by
$$u(x)=A\cos x+{x\over2}\sin x\ ,$$
and the second equation $(1)$ then gives
$$v(x)=u'(x)={1\over2}\bigl(x\cos x+(1-2A)\sin x\bigr)\ .$$
This leads to
$$f(x)=u(x)+v(x)=A(\cos x-\sin x)+{1\over2}\sin x+{x\over2}(\cos x+\sin x)\ .$$
It remains to check whether such $f$s indeed satisfy the originally given condition. I can leave this to you.

Comment: It is crystal clear ! Thank you Christian and Lutzl !

Comment: @lostinmath: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer, if you have enough reputation to do so. In addition, accept the best answer (if it actually answers your question) by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment. It also helps others to see that your question was answered.